# Response not received back to client from Apigee Cloud

Tags: apigee

POSTMANCleint-->  Apigee OnCloud-->Apigee On Premise---->Backend

Backend is taking 67 sec to respond and i can see the response in Apigee cloud as well however the same response is not sent to client and instead timeout is received .

I have also increased the timeout counts on HTTTargetConnectionProperties  but still the issue persists.

Please let us know where to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two levels of timeout in Apigee -- first at the load balancer which has a 60 second timeout, then at the Apigee layer which I believe was 30 seconds but looks like it was increased to 60.

My guess is that the timeout response is coming from the load balancer and that the the timing is just such that Apigee is able to get the response but the load balancer has already dropped the connection.

If this is a paid instance you should be able to get Apigee to adjust the timeouts to make this work (but, man... 67,000ms response times are pretty long...)

Comment: Thanks Mike, got a case logged and the response says that the Router-Message Processor has a timeout configured at 58 sec and the  router-client is 55 secs.  It will require changes in APigee on cloud to support atleast 60 sec timeout.

Comment: No problem -- do me a favor and accept the answer so SO will see this as answered (and I get my reputation points!)